# Greenplum: copy data between tables

Tags: sql, sql-insert, greenplum

I'm need copy data from table1 and table 2 in table3
I'ms try execute this request:

```
WITH sel AS (
    SELECT 
        er.local_company_pk as "local_company_pk",
        dv.load_dtm as "load_dtm",
        dv.src as "rec_src",
        dv.companyogrn as "ogrn",
        dv."CompanyID" as "company_spark_id",
        dv.companyvat as "company_vat",
        dv."CompanyCountryCode" as "company_country_code",
        dv."CompanyShortName" as "company_short_name",
        dv."CompanyFullName" as "company_full_name",
        dv."CompanySize" as "company_size",
        dv."CompanyRevenue" as "company_revenue",
        dv."StaffQuantity" as "staff_quantity",
        dv."CompanyRegionName" as "company_region_name",
        dv."CompanyCityName" as "company_city_name",
        dv."RegistrationDT" as "registration_dt",
        dv."EndDT" as "end_dt",
        dv."CompanyStatus" as "company_status",
        dv."FailureIndex" as "failure_index",
        dv."IndexOfDueDiligence" as "index_of_due_diligence",
        dv."ConsolidateIndex" as "consolidate_index",
        ' ' as "hash_diff"
    FROM
        table1 as dv,
        table2 as er
    WHERE 
        er.inn = dv.companyvat
    LIMIT 10
)
INSERT INTO
    table3
SELECT * 
FROM sel
```

And I have error `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"`

How I can insert into table3 from select between table1 and table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a CTE?

```
INSERT INTO table3
   SELECT 
        er.local_company_pk as "local_company_pk",
        dv.load_dtm as "load_dtm",
        dv.src as "rec_src",
        dv.companyogrn as "ogrn",
        dv."CompanyID" as "company_spark_id",
        dv.companyvat as "company_vat",
        dv."CompanyCountryCode" as "company_country_code",
        dv."CompanyShortName" as "company_short_name",
        dv."CompanyFullName" as "company_full_name",
        dv."CompanySize" as "company_size",
        dv."CompanyRevenue" as "company_revenue",
        dv."StaffQuantity" as "staff_quantity",
        dv."CompanyRegionName" as "company_region_name",
        dv."CompanyCityName" as "company_city_name",
        dv."RegistrationDT"::text as "registration_dt",
---------------------------^ you can cast the value
        dv."EndDT" as "end_dt",
        dv."CompanyStatus" as "company_status",
        dv."FailureIndex" as "failure_index",
        dv."IndexOfDueDiligence" as "index_of_due_diligence",
        dv."ConsolidateIndex" as "consolidate_index",
        ' ' as hash_diff
    FROM table1 as dv JOIN
         table2 as er
         ON er.inn = dv.companyvat
    LIMIT 10
```

I also fixed your broken `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I'm try use INSERT INTO wiht SELECT (now I fix JOIN syntax, thanks) and I have another error: ```  SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "registration_dt" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.```

Answer (score 0):

How is registration_dt defined in table3?  If it is a date already, there is no need to cast it in your SELECT.  The error message indicates it is defined as a date.